# .htaccess mod_rewrite for nested folder structuring

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, nested, subdirectory

I recently found an article online that told me about this:

```
RewriteRule ^mock-up/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /mock-up/index.php?page=$1&section=$2 [NC]
```

Only thing that is driving me crazy right now is if I want to be able to have the 2nd directory or not.  Like:

```
RewriteRule ^mock-up/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /mock-up/index.php?page=$1&section=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^mock-up/([^/]+) /mock-up/index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

But that's breaking apache... so what to do?  Please help, I need to seo for my client and I would prefer not to have to make individual files for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `mock-up/index.php` is also matched by `mock-up/([^/]+)`. So you need to exclude the target, either directly:

```
RewriteRule ^mock-up/index\.php$ - [L]
```

Or indirectly:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

So try this:

```
RewriteRule ^mock-up/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^mock-up/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /mock-up/index.php?page=$1&section=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^mock-up/([^/]+)$ /mock-up/index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, i rarely ever touch .htaccess unless i need to, but i noticed wordpress implements this clever strategy.

that works, but other files in that 'mock-up' directory are no longer showing up, so do have any suggestions?

i appreciate your help!